# Is there any way to get all the blog posts to use in another component?

Tags: docusaurus

I've been looking for any hooks or API by `plugin-content-blog` to get all the blog posts in `json` format under folder `blog` because I want to use the data in another component but seems like there's none. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure this out?